# Десериализация json. Распарсить некорректный enum

Tags: java, json

На `API` контроллер отправляю `json` из `postman`-а, что-то вроде:

```
{
  "name": "Ivan",
  "lastName": "Ivanov",
  "activity": "student"
}
```

У меня есть класс с несколькими полями, один из которых enum. Просто пример:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    Activity activity;
}

enum Activity {
    @JsonProperty("teacher")
    TEACHER,
    @JsonProperty("student")
    STUDENT,
    @JsonProperty("unknown")
    UNKNOWN;
}
```

Мне нужно из `json` получить объект `Person`. Но нужно учесть, что для поля `activity` в `json` может быть указано любое значение, и в случае, если это не `teacher` или `student`, нужно присвоить полю `activity` значение `unknown`.

Если я пытаюсь распарсить `json`  с известным значением `enum`, то всё проходит успешно, создаётся объект `Person`. Но если в `json` для поля `activity` указать любое другое значение, то объект не создаётся, я получаю `bad request` в постмане.
Пытался указывать разные аннотации для `enum` `unknown`, но ничего не выходит.

Как распарсить `json`, в котором для поля `activity` будет введено неизвестное значение `enum`-а и в итоге экземпляру класса `Person` для поля `activity` было присвоено значение `unknown`?

Comment: зачем в enum @JsonProperty? вам наверное Person свойства нужно мапить? В json enum будет просто числом которое дессереализируется в enum на другой стороне

Comment: Данный код был написан не мной и в принципе он работает. Но если на апи присылают json с неизвестным значением для поля activity, то объект не создаётся. Нужно учесть, что может прийти любое значение для поля activity и в этом случае объект все равно должен быть создан с полем activity = unknown. Я не совсем понял ваш комментарий. Вы предлагаете удалить все аннотации из енама и будет работать?

Comment: по умолчанию enum будет 0, поставьте UNKNOWN первым или задайте последовательность явно

Comment: мапить enum внутри не вижу смысла, у вас должен быть на обеих сторонах одинаковый enum в плане последовательности

Comment: Что значит "задайте последовательность явно"? enum Activity {
    UNKNOWN,
    TEACHER,
    STUDENT;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться аннотацией `@JsonEnumDefaultValue`:

```
package com.somepackage;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonEnumDefaultValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

public class Main {

    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class Person {
        String name;
        String lastName;
        Activity activity;
    }

    enum Activity {
        @JsonProperty("teacher")
        TEACHER,
        @JsonProperty("student")
        STUDENT,
        @JsonProperty("unknown")
        @JsonEnumDefaultValue
        UNKNOWN;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str =
                "{\n" +
                "  \"name\": \"Ivan\",\n" +
                "  \"lastName\": \"Ivanov\",\n" +
                "  \"activity\": \"activity\"\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper =
                new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(
                DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE);
        Person person =
                objectMapper.readValue(
                        str, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Main.Person(name=Ivan, lastName=Ivanov, activity=UNKNOWN)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень выручили! До этого самостоятельно пробовал аннотацию @JsonEnumDefaultValue, но без строчки objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE); Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!